# Simple water demand supply model in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, data.table, recurrence

I am trying to work out a simple soil water balance in R. Here's the step I need to do:

For a given year, starting from doy 200,I need to determine the Soil Water (SWi) which is calculated by following formula

```
              `SW(i) = SW(i-1)  + Rain(i) - ETo(i)`
```

where `SW(i-1)` is the water content in previous day, `Rain(i)` is the rainfall and `ETo(i)` is the evapotranspiration on day i

The conditions are that SW(i) cannot be negative or be more than SW(max) which is 20.

Here's a sample data:

```
        library(tidyverse)
        set.seed(123)

        dat <- tibble(
              year = rep(1980:2015, each = 100),
              day = rep(200:299, times = 36),
              rain = sample(0:17, size = 100*36,replace = T),
              eto = sample(2:9, size = 100*36,replace = T))

        SW.initial <- data.frame(year= 1980:2015, SW.199 = sample(1:10, 36, replace = T))
```

SW.initial is the water content for doy 199 for for each year

```
        SW.max <- 20 
        dat$SW.fin <- NA
```

Taking the example of year 1980

```
        dat.1980 <- dat[dat$year == 1980,]
        SW.initial.1980 <- SW.initial[SW.initial$year== 1980,"SW.199"]

        for(doy in dat.1980$day){

            SW <- SW.initial.1980 
            SW <- SW + dat.1980[dat.1980$day == doy, "rain"] - dat.1980[dat.1980$day == doy, "eto"]
            SW <- ifelse(SW < 0, 0, ifelse(SW >= SW.max, SW.max, SW))
            dat[dat$year == years & dat$day == doy,"SW.fin"] <- SW
            SW.initial.1980 <- SW
          }
```

This loop will give me the SW of each day starting doy 200 till 299 using:

```
      `SW(i) = SW(i-1) + Rain[i] + ETo[i]``
```

where for doy 200, SW(i-1) was given from the `SW.initial` data frame

I can loop through all years:

```
        for(years in unique(dat$year)){
                test <- dat[dat$year == years,]
                SW.in <- SW.initial[SW.initial$year == years,"SW.199"]
              for(doy in test$day){
                    SW <- SW.in 
                    SW <- SW + test[test$day == doy, "rain"] - test[test$day == doy, "eto"]
                    SW <- ifelse(SW < 0, 0, ifelse(SW >= SW.max, SW.max, SW))
                    dat[dat$year == years & dat$day == doy,"SW.fin"] <- SW
                    SW.in <- SW
          }}
```

I really want to avoid this long loop and was thinking if there is much clever (and faster way to do this).

Comment: "and faster way to do this" - solve the recurrence mathematically?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment. I do not have a maths background

Comment: What do you assume for day 200 each year ? The first year, you seem to say that SW = 1 at the begining, but for the following years SW increase by one ... I can't get the meaning of that, and, moreover, this initial SW goes over 20 after 20 years .. what does it mean ?

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question now. I realise where I was making a mistake in terms of explaining the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this give what you want ?

**edit** -> added grouped by year

```
dat %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(sw_oneless = c(NA, day[1:length(day)-1]),
               sw_oneless + rain - eto)

    # A tibble: 3,600 x 6
# Groups: year [36]
    year   day  rain   eto sw_oneless `sw_oneless + rain - eto`
   <int> <int> <int> <int>      <int>                     <int>
 1  1980   200     5     2         NA                        NA
 2  1980   201    14     6        200                       208
 3  1980   202     7     4        201                       204
 4  1980   203    15     5        202                       212
 5  1980   204    16     5        203                       214
 6  1980   205     0     8        204                       196
 7  1980   206     9     9        205                       205
 8  1980   207    16     6        206                       216
 9  1980   208     9     9        207                       207
10  1980   209     8     4        208                       212
# ... with 3,590 more rows
```

To solve the "problem" with day 200, why don't you just filter out day 199-300 from your original data? You can then run my code and na.omit() or filter again and the rows with day 199 are gone.
Or, if you can't do that, merge your SW.initial with your dat data frame

Comment: Not really.  For 1980, day 200, sw_oneless should have a value of  `sw_onless.1980.200 = SW.initial[year ==1980,] + rain.200 - eto.200`; `sw_onless.1980.201 = sw_onless.1980.200 + rain.201 - eto.201`; `sw_onless.1980.202 = sw_onless.1980.201 + rain.202 - eto.202` and so on.

Comment: @KS89 .. with this answer, and a bit of  `ifelse`  .. you should be able to get what you want ..

Comment: I need to do it separately for all years. The above code doesn't group the data according to years.

Comment: Also it would be useful to compare the time this function takes versus what my solution is. Hence, I need a complete code so that time comparison can be done. Thank you

Comment: group_by(year) ?

Comment: added suggestion for your "200 problem"

Comment: Thank you. I cant figure out what is `c(NA, day[1:length(day)-1]),` this doing in the code

Comment: This is creating a dummy column with one row shifted. The values of the first row will start at the second position of your data frame. As a data frame needs always the same length , you have to assign a value (in this case I chose 'NA') to the first row and you have to omit the last row of the original column (therefore length - 1)